# Creating a .bat file that disables my computer's logo

Tags: windows, batch

I have a win10 "monster" notebook (brand is not so popular worldwide so you might not know it) and it has a cool feature that it displays the logo of the brand below the touchpad to the desk. It's cool red light kind of a thing. So anyways everytime I start my computer the light opens up and I go into somekind of a control panel made specifially for this brand and from settings I turn it off. But repeating this process every single time when I open the pc is a little annoying. So I was thinking if there would be any way to create a .bat file sort of thing and made it turn off the light so I can throw it into start up folder and let the pc turn it off by itself? Any feedback is much appreciated

Edit: I used process monitor to figure out registry changes whenever I turn off the light bar. I found the value but there's a problem. Whenever I use control panel and turn light bar off, related registry value changes from 1 to 0, BUT when I change it directly from the regedit file, nothing happens. Value changes to 0 but light is still on. Any ideas?

Edit2: I contacted support, they said control panel panel should've saved my settings everytime pc opens, but apparently it has a problem. So no luck

Comment: Have you asked Monster Support about it?  If they've made an API available, then it might be scriptable.  However, their control panel's setting should stick between restarts.  I suggest contacting their support.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'll edit my post once they respond

Comment: From what I see there they're support is lacking. And FAQs are the worse. They about only handle shipping at the .ae site (from what I have seen). Hope it works out for you. Good Gaming!

Comment: We might be talking about different brands vssher. "Monster" brand I'm talking about is actually Turkish and they answered every question I asked them within 24 hours. They handled every problems (even problems with cargo companies) so far for me. There might be a similar named brand with problems you talk about though

Comment: I would expect that additional hardware features that are enabled by default can be configured in the BIOS.